# Iterate array [] with angular

Tags: angular

I have the following answer when I call an api..

I have more attributes than this but I think that is better shorter then

```
{
   "id":1,
   "FirstQuarter":[
      {
         "id":1,         
         "PLAYINFO":"Begin Period"
      }
   ]
```

There are models with angular

```
export class Match {
    id: number;
    live: boolean;
    teamA: String;
    teamB: String;
    codeTeamA: String;
    codeTeamB: String;
    actualQuarter: number;
    header: Header;
    FirstQuarter: FirstQuarter[];
}

export class FirstQuarter {   
    id: number;    
}
```

This is my component :

```
export class PlayByPlayComponent implements OnInit {
  match:Match;

  constructor(private _playByPlayService:PlayByPlayService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    var matchId = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('matchId');
    this.getPlayByPlay(matchId);
  } 

  getPlayByPlay(matchId:String){ 
       
    this._playByPlayService.getPlayByPlaySyncronized(matchId).subscribe(    
      data=>{  
        this.match= JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));   
      },
      (error)=>{
        console.log("Error");
      }
    );
  }
}
```

And I have the following service folder

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PlayByPlayService {

  private basketball:string = environment.basketball;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getPlayByPlaySyncronized(matchId:String): Observable<any>{    
    return this.http.get(this.basketball+"/api/public/v1/match/"+matchId);    
  }
 
}
```

I am rendering the result in angular template like

```
{{match.id}}
{{match.gameCode}}
{{match.gameCode}}
{{match.TeamA}}
<table class="table table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">ID</th>
      <th scope="col"></th>       
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let match of match.FirstQuarter">
      <td>{{match.id}}</td>
    </tr>  
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And it prints like followin image , but I couldn't print the firstQuarter

[image]

The complete log using console.log

[image]

Comment: You should give more info. For example if you `console.log(data)` inside the subscribe, what does it look like?

Comment: I'd suppose you see errors in your browser console as `match` is definitely undefined at start. Can you confirm this? Or is your console free from errors?

Comment: Your model is wrong. Change `export class FirstQuarter {   
    id: number;    
}` to `export class FirstQuarter {   
    id: number; 
   "PLAYINFO": string
}`

Comment: @eko I attached an image how look likes.

Comment: Ok could you try changing the `let match` part of `let match of match.FirstQuarter` to something else like `let elem of match.FirstQuarter` and `<td>{{elem.id}}</td>` accordingly